# Change F2 to be Ctrl+F in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

How do I change <kbd>F2</kbd> to equal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>? Here are two things I've tried:

```
F2::Send {Control F}
F2::ControlSend, F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F2::
  Send ^f
return
```

Works for me. Although you need to watch out as I believe there are some programs that act differently on <kbd>F2</kbd>. For example, doesn't seem to work in Outlook.

Comment: You won't believe this, but doing a Ctrl+F in notepad doesn't work if there's nothing in untitled. It only works after you type something in to begin with. I guess that's why it wasn't working.  Thanks Kassym!